# Un proverbe français équivalant à « What's good for the goose is good for the gander » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, proverbes

Existe-t-il un proverbe français équivalent à l'expression idiomatique anglaise « *What's good for the goose is good for the gander* » ?

Je suis à la recherche d'un proverbe et non d'une traduction littérale (comme, par exemple, *Ce qui est bon pour l'oie est bon pour le jars*).

Comment: A bon chat, bon rat ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait un « proverbe » à proprement parler qui ait cette connotation. Toutefois, une expression assez commune existe qui exprime ce sens : *ce qui vaut pour l'un vaut aussi pour l'autre*.

Dans un registre plus métaphorique, une traduction qui a été utilisée au parlement canadien et que j'aime bien est *Ce qui est bon pour pitou est bon pour minou*, mais je ne crois pas que les Européens emploient « pitou » comme terme affectueux pour un chien.

Comment: Effectivement, en tant que Français, je devine ce que « Ce qui est bon pour pitou est bon pour minou » veut dire, mais sans ce message je me demanderais ce qu'est un pitou.

Comment: Étonnamment on dirait que le proverbe opposé «  Ce qui est bon pour pitou n'est pas bon pour minou. » existe aussi…

Answer (score 2):

Il y a quelque chose pour exprimer l'injustice lorsque le *gander* et la *goose* ont des comportements différents:

> Deux poids, deux mesures

Et lorsqu'on veut réparer l'injustice, on peut invoquer le talion:

> Œil pour œil, dent pour dent

Answer (score 1):

> Un prêté pour un rendu

s'emploierait dans un sens similaire de « tu me l'as fait, je te l'ai fait aussi ».

Sinon il y a toujours la règle biblique,

> Ne fais pas aux autres ce que tu ne veux pas qu'on te fasse.

Answer (score 1):

Nous sommes tous logés à la même enseigne.